# Is this the correct way to use the boost::scope_ptr with array?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-smart-ptr

Since boost::scoped_ptr doesn't work with [] indexing operator, I am trying to do a workaround like this

```
{
    boost::scoped_ptr<float> data_ptr;
    float *data = new float(SIZE);
    data_ptr.reset(data);
    ...
}
```

Will the array be freed later on? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float *data = new float(SIZE);
```

This line dynamically allocates a single `float` and initializes it to `SIZE`, it isn't allocating an array of `SIZE` elements. The code you've shown has well defined behavior, other than the fact that it's obviously not what you want.

To dynamically allocate an array use

```
float *data = new float[SIZE];
//                     ^    ^
// use "new float[SIZE]()" if you want to zero initialize all the elements
```

However, if you do that your code now has undefined behavior because the `scoped_ptr` will call `delete` to destroy the array, but because allocated the memory using `new[]`, you need `delete[]` to be called instead. The solution is to use [`boost::scoped_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm).

```
{
    boost::scoped_array<float> data_ptr(new float[SIZE]);

    data_ptr[0] = 0;  // array indexing works too
    ...
}  // delete[] will be called to destroy the array
```